# When changeRootViewController, unknow error appears:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

Tags: swift, xcode

I try to change rootViewController using swift code to log out and it seems a memory error appears:
[image: error code]

The code of log out is as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let section = SettingsSection(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {return}
    
    switch section {
    case .Profile:
        print(ProfileOptions(rawValue: indexPath.row)?.description)
        if ProfileOptions(rawValue: indexPath.row)?.description == "Log Out"{
            //logoutTapped()
            //return
            userDefaults.set("", forKey: Keys.username)
            userDefaults.set("", forKey: Keys.useremail)
            
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loginNavController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginNavController")
            (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.changeRootViewController(loginNavController)
        }
        break
        
    case .Application:
        print(ApplicationOptions(rawValue: indexPath.row)?.description)
    }
}
```

changeRootViewController Code in SceneDelegate:

```
func changeRootViewController(_ vc: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true) {
    guard let window = self.window else {
        return
    }
    window.rootViewController = vc
    // add animations
    UIView.transition(with: window,
                      duration: 0.5,
                      options: [.transitionCurlDown],
                      animations: nil,
                      completion: nil)
}
```

I followed this tutorial: https://fluffy.es/how-to-transition-from-login-screen-to-tab-bar-controller/
Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For doing it you have to store your current RootView in coreData. You have to preload Base RootView for the first time opening your app by using CoreData.

I have been also making an app with possibility for such changing, and the hardest thing was to find info about pre loading data for the first run of your app

So here is the code I used:

You will have to preload data in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

//Do not forget to set the function
preloadDataFromStructArray()

```
            return true
    }
    
    func preloadDataFromStructArray() {
        
        let preloadedDataKey = "didPreloadData"
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        if userDefaults.bool(forKey: preloadedDataKey) == false {

            let someViewController1 = isCurrent(index: 0, status: false)
            let someViewController2 = isCurrent(index: 1, status: false)
            
            let backgroundContext = CoreDataStack.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
            CoreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            
            backgroundContext.perform {
                
                    let arrayViewControllersStatuses = [someViewController1, someViewController2]
                    
                    do{
                    
                    for status in arrayViewControllersStatuses {

                        let viewControllerStatus = CurrentTrainingPlan(context: backgroundContext)
                        viewControllerStatus = status.status!
                        viewControllerStatus = status.index!
                        
                    }
                    
                        try backgroundContext.save()
                        userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: preloadedDataKey)

                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                
            }
                        
        }
        
    }
```